# Undo tablespace full, how to free it

Tags: oracle-10g, tablespaces

My undo tablespace is full after some modifications. Las column is % of space used.

xxx_undo_01.dbf UNDO    2147483648  16777216    2048    2032    16  0,78    99,22

Now i cannot execute any query according to this. How can i free the undo tablespace ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add another datafile to the UNDO tablespace to get you by in the short term?  e.g.: `ALTER TABLESPACE undotbs_01
     ADD DATAFILE '/u01/oracle/rbdb1/undo0102.dbf' AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1M 
         MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;
` Taken from [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/undo005.htm)

Comment: I can't add another datafile. I want to free the undo tablespace. I've all the operations/chages commited. I think it should reduce the data stored after the operations are commited.

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to run a query?

Answer (score -1):

You can execute below query.

DROP TABLESPACE xxx_undo_01 INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;

Comment: This should erase also the datafile of the undo tablespace. I only want to free some space.